SPAM and SPOOF emails from postfix mailserver
I created and configured a postfix server, basically its an smtp-only server. I added the domain i want to use in postfix main.cf, and also added other domains in virtual file. I installed configured Opendkim Opendmarc, I also added the Public records:
DKIM, Opendmarc, SPF. Everything passed in the header when i send an email from within the mail server using telnet localhost 25..
Though everything is passing my email messages are still getting into the junk folder of recipients, they are labeled as spam and outlook is labeling them as SPOOF.
Am i missing anything i should configure?

Does this answer your question? How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?

I looked into that, though i got DKIM SPF and dmarc setup and also checked for blacklist on ip and domains nothing seems to be out of the ordinary, also mail-tester.com is giving me a good score and confirming my mail should reach most inboxes though its reaching spam and labelled as spoof, i just noticed that the mail server is allowing me to send emails using domains that arent available in the .conf file or the virtual file, so im looking into this since it didnt let me do that before maybe thats the reason my mails are getting labelled spoof since everything else is setup correctly
